# angular not defined in wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

Im trying to use angular in my wordpress plugin, I included it like this:

```
    wp_register_script('jquery-custom', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-custom");
    wp_register_script('angular', ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script("angular");
```

It seems like it is included but I still get "angular is not defined" in my console when I try to use it

Comment: I tried including angular-resource and angular-route too

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem,
Angular was loaded after my code as wp_enqueue_script includes it at the end of the file.

This it is kinda a dirty solution but I resolved it by simply including the angular.min.js in the html way.

```
wp_register_script('jquery-custom', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"), false);
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-custom");
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<?php
```